# CORS настройка сервера

Tags: веб-программирование, nginx, cors

На удаленном сервере установил backend и frontend web-приложения, с данного сервера доступ к приложению есть. В файле `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` на своей машине прописал на какой ip резолвить доменное имя c моего компьютера, сервер и мой компьютер находятся в одной VPN сети.

В браузере ввожу доменное имя, по которому откликается приложение, и спокойно вхожу в приложение.

Если же проделать это с другого компьютера, так же находящегося а данной VPN сети, в консоле браузера выводится

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://xxxxx.xxx.ru/login' from
>   origin 'http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.
>
> Error: Network Error
>       at e.exports (createError.js:16)    at XMLHttpRequest.d.onerror (xhr.js:87)

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Какое именно слово вам непонятно во фразах «blocked by CORS policy» и «No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present»?

Comment: Почему на одном компьютере работает а на другом нет

Comment: Потому что на одном компьютере доменные имена страницы и приложения совпадают, а на другом не совпадают.

Comment: Для обхода нужно на сервере настройки менять? я использую nginx

Comment: Для начала почитайте, что такое CORS

Comment: Почитал, но как решить проблему не нашел, при этом если обращаться по ip, то с моего работает, с другого компа нет